# How do I delete all tasks whose names begin with "AliUpdater"?

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduled-tasks

```
schtasks /delete /tn "AliUpdater" /f
```

The above will delete only  "**AliUpdater**". Is it possible to delete all tasks whose names begin with "**AliUpdater**", for example "**AliUpdater{123}**", "**AliUpdater{456}**", and "**AliUpdater{789}**"? The unwanted task "**AliUpdater**" comes with various numbers. It is impossible to predict the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to still use [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) instead of [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), *(which is outside of the scope of your provided question tags)*:

```dos
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=\" %# In ('SchTasks /Query /FO List^|Find /I "AliUpdater"')Do @SchTasks /Delete /TN "%$" /F
```

Comment: I ran your command line and got this message: **`ERROR: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`**

Comment: @MatthewWai, it is likely that you must have failed to do what my post shows then. To be clear, how are you running the above? What do you get, with this, `SchTasks /Query /FO List|Find /I "AliUpdater"`? What do you get with this, `For /F "Delims=" %# In ('SchTasks /Query /FO List^|Find /I "AliUpdater"')Do @Echo "%#"`. _(obviously, based upon your tags, both inside [tag:cmd], not in a [tag:batch-file])._

Comment: I right-clicked on the "**Start**" button-->"**Windows PowerShell (Admin)**" and ran "**cmd**".  Then I ran **`SchTasks /Query /FO List|Find /I "AliUpdater"`** and got **`TaskName:      \AliUpdater{123}`**.  Then I ran **`For /F "Delims=" %# In ('SchTasks /Query /FO List^|Find /I "AliUpdater"')Do @Echo "%#"`** and got **`"TaskName:      \AliUpdater{123}"`**.  Then I ran **`For /F "Delims=" %# In ('SchTasks /Query /FO List^|Find /I "AliUpdater"')Do @SchTasks /Delete /TN "%#" /F`** and got **`ERROR: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`**.

Comment: @MatthewWai, I have edited my answer to incorporate the important information you've now provided.

Comment: With "**`Tokens=1*`**", it works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using PowerShell if possible.  [Get-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/get-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps) will accept wildcards for the task name:

To have it confirm each task:

```
Get-ScheduledTask "AliUpdater*" | Unregister-ScheduledTask
```

No confirmation:

```
Get-ScheduledTask "AliUpdater*" | Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. If the task name contains a space, quotation marks are needed:   **`Get-ScheduledTask "Task name*" | Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false`onfirm:$false`**