# Find all scheduled Windows tasks that contain "UPDATE" in the name, via CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, syntax, scheduled-tasks

In trying to figure out how to programmatically list certain tasks from the Windows Task Planner, I found this:
[How do I delete all tasks whose names begin with "AliUpdater"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59332485/how-do-i-delete-all-tasks-whose-names-begin-with-aliupdater) with a batch syntax by @Compo.

Starting from there, I put together below batch query in order to find all tasks that contain “UPDATE” in the name:

```
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=\" %# In ('SchTasks /Query /FO List^|Find /I "UPDATE"')Do @SchTasks /ShowSid "%$"
```

However, the syntax doesn't seem to be completely right because -- while it does list all tasks containing "update" -- I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid Option / Argument - "[FullTaskPath\TaskName]"
```

...after every listed task.

Further, when searching for "ZEIT" in the task name this way, strangely it doesn't find any task (but instead lists all tasks):

```
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=\" %# In ('SchTasks /Query /FO List^|Find /I "ZEIT"')Do @SchTasks /ShowSid "%$"
```

...while when searching for "ZEITG", it **does** find four tasks containing "zeitg":

```
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=\" %# In ('SchTasks /Query /FO List^|Find /I "ZEITG"')Do @SchTasks /ShowSid "%$"
```

What could be wrong with my batch query syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You have not explained what you're trying to achieve, and appear to have multiple questions, each with a different command snippet and issue.

This example is therefore based only upon your first code snippet, *(getting the tasknames containing the case insensitive string `UPDATE` and returning those with their computed `SID`)*, as this site deals with one specific issue per question.

Directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```sh
For /F Delims^=^" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Query /FO CSV /NH 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "UPDATE"') Do @For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /ShowSid /TN "%G" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "SUCCESS:"') Do @Echo(%G:%H
```

In a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For /F Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Query /FO CSV
 /NH 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "UPDATE"'
) Do For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe
 /ShowSid /TN "%%G" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "SUCCESS:"'
) Do Echo(%%G:%%H
Pause
```

*Please note however that I've found the output to schtasks.exe to be pretty unreliable at times, so this may not always produce all of the output you expected of it.*

Comment: Not sure why, but your CMD code does not list any tasks here, while my first snippet from above (while throwing an Invalid Option / Argument Error after every entry) lists about 50 tasks containing the text "update" in their name (or path).

Comment: I've just tested that exact line, *(on this computer, I'm supposed to be repairing)*, and it almost immediately returned 33 lines of output in exactly the format I expected. I additionally tested the batch-file, which produced exaclty the same expected 33 lines of output too!

Comment: BTW, the common specific issue of my original question is finding the syntax error in my query (which has the same syntax in all snippets).

Comment: That's strange, because what I get in an elevated CMD prompt is this:
https://pastebin.com/GQKSJn8A

Comment: Very strange @David.P, because I've just done the same and get, 62 lines of output in exactly the format I expected, obviously 29 of those tasks are returned extra, due to the elevation token in effect when Run as administrator. Please remember however to read my footnote, in my experience, the output from shtasks.exe is not to be relied on in isolation. You may find that the only way to get everything, possible without errors, is to run your batch file as SYSTEM, which would mean you'd have to run it as a scheduled task itself.

Comment: OK thanks Compo. Do you by any chance know an answer to this: https://superuser.com/questions/1656494/where-are-scheduled-tasks-stored-in-an-offline-windows-10-partition-hard-drive

Comment: BTW., this is what I get with my original snippet: https://pastebin.com/GuyYGHKD

Comment: Based upon the output from your link above, `schtasks.exe` may output localized strings. You may need to change the English string `"SUCCESS:"`, to its German equivalent too.